# python mysql insert query with auto increment

Tags: python, mysql

When I try to execute

```
queryTwo = ("""INSERT INTO teams (name) VALUES ('bar')""")
```

Nothing happens.

I have a simple 2 column DB:

```
team_id    name
  1       One
  2       Two
```

I create the table with

```
CREATE TABLE teams (
  team_id int(2) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have run a query with auto increment off, and I could succesfully run a query and insert. So I know there's a working db connection. But for the logic of primary key, I want it to auto increment everytime I insert a new row.

UPDATE: I tried debug with

```
newID = cursor.lastrowid
print(newID)
```

The result is that everytime I run the code I can see an incremented number in the console. So something is "happening". But if I refresh my table in my workbench there's nothing to show for.

I tried to run it on the server (the "command promp" program) And it'll show the same as the workbench.

Comment: Do you check for sql errors after executing the query? Is there any sql error message? There is nothing obviously wrong with your code.

Comment: This should not happen, maybe you **forgot to commit your insert query** when auto_increment is on?

Comment: There's no error messages. I updated the post with a new edit. I think it's commiting, because I have not changed anything in my code. And it works if I dont use auto increment

Comment: add auto_commit=True in .connect?

Comment: @piglei I had to commit yes. Thanks for that! I just think it's strange that I could insert without commit if I don't use auto increment.